# How can I render a Matplotlib Axes object to an image (as a Numpy array)?

Tags: matplotlib

Is there a way to render the contents of a particular Axes object to an image, as a Numpy array? I know you can do this with the entire figure, but I want to get the image of a particular Axes.

The Axes I'm trying to render contains an image (drawn with imshow), with some lines plotted on top. Ideally, the rendered ndarray would contain just these elements, and no tick marks, borders, etc.

#### Update:

I forgot to mention that I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require saving an image file.

I've written the following example that almost achieves this, except it doesn't preserve image resolution. Any hints as to what I may be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

def main():
  """Test for extracting pixel data from an Axes.

  This creates an image I, imshow()'s it to one Axes, then copies the pixel
  data out of that Axes to a numpy array I_copy, and imshow()'s the I_copy to
  another Axes.

  Problem: The two Axes *look* identical, but I does not equal I_copy.
  """

  fig, axes_pair = plt.subplots(1, 2)

  reds, greens = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 255), np.arange(0, 122))
  blues = np.zeros_like(reds)
  image = np.concatenate([x[..., np.newaxis] for x in (reds, greens, blues)],
                         axis=2)
  image = np.asarray(image, dtype=np.uint8)

  axes_pair[0].imshow(image)
  fig.canvas.draw()

  trans = axes_pair[0].figure.dpi_scale_trans.inverted()
  bbox = axes_pair[0].bbox.transformed(trans)
  bbox_contents = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(axes_pair[0].bbox)
  left, bottom, right, top = bbox_contents.get_extents()

  image_copy = np.fromstring(bbox_contents.to_string(),
                             dtype=np.uint8,
                             sep="")

  image_copy = image_copy.reshape([top - bottom, right - left, 4])
  image_copy = image_copy[..., :3]  # chop off alpha channel

  axes_pair[1].imshow(image_copy)

  print("Are the images perfectly equal? {}".format(np.all(image == image_copy)))

  plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Do you want the resulting image to be as large (in pixels) as the original one, or do you not care about the resolution?

Comment: Yes, the rendered image should be the same resolution as what I see on the screen when plotting.

Answer (score 3):

One idea can be to intermediately turn the axes off, find out the bounding box of the axes in inches and then save the figure using the `bbox_inches` argument to `plt.savefig()`.

If a numpy array is wanted, one can then read in the saved image again using `plt.imread`.

In this solution the returned array has dimensions exactly as the axes has pixels when plotted on the screen.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)

im = np.random.rand(16,16)

x = np.arange(9)
y = np.random.randint(1,14, size=(9,))
y2 = np.random.randint(1,7, size=(9,))

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

ax1.imshow(im[:16,:9], cmap="viridis")
ax2.imshow(im[7:16,7:], cmap="YlGnBu")
ax1.plot(x, y, color="C3")
ax1.scatter(x, y, color="w")
ax2.plot(x, y2, color="C1")
ax2.scatter(x, y2, color="k")
ax1.set_xlabel("YlFasOcto")

def save_ax(ax, filename, **kwargs):
    ax.axis("off")
    ax.figure.canvas.draw()
    trans = ax.figure.dpi_scale_trans.inverted() 
    bbox = ax.bbox.transformed(trans)
    plt.savefig(filename, dpi="figure", bbox_inches=bbox,  **kwargs)
    ax.axis("on")
    im = plt.imread(filename)
    return im

arr = save_ax(ax1, __file__+".png")
print(arr.shape)
plt.show()
```

In order to prevent saving a file to disk, one could use a Stream to save the data.

```
import io

def save_ax_nosave(ax, **kwargs):
    ax.axis("off")
    ax.figure.canvas.draw()
    trans = ax.figure.dpi_scale_trans.inverted() 
    bbox = ax.bbox.transformed(trans)
    buff = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buff, format="png", dpi=ax.figure.dpi, bbox_inches=bbox,  **kwargs)
    ax.axis("on")
    buff.seek(0)
    im = plt.imread(buff )
    return im
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't been able to run your code (our Matplotlib versions may differ). I've updated my question with some example code of my own, which borrows your idea of using dpi_scale_trans.inverted(), but doesn't need to save out to a file (a necessary property I forgot to mention). It mostly does what I want, *except* for preserving the resolution of the originally imshow'ed image. Which is a problem.

Comment: "I haven't been able to run your code" is not a sufficient problem description. Initially I did try a similar solution as the one from the question, using `to_string()` method, but the image was shifted compared to the original. I therefore came up with the solution in this answer. I updated the answer to include the case where no output file is desired.