# Is it possible to get an image from Pyplot as numpy array after it was shown with .imshow in a subplot?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I know how to extract the image if it was rendered in its own subplot, like desribed here:

[Matplotlib figure to image as a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355930/matplotlib-figure-to-image-as-a-numpy-array)

However, I have a slightly different code, which looks like the following:

```
_, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(20,20))


height, width = image.shape[:2]
ax.set_ylim(height + 10, -10)
ax.set_xlim(-10, width + 10)
ax.axis('off')
ax.set_title(title)
ax.text(x,y,"blabla")
#...some more things happen with ax here

some_image = 255*np.random.rand(20,20)
some_image = some_image.astype(np.uint8)

#Somethings happen with the image here
#....


ax.imshow(some_image.astype(np.uint8))
```

Is it possible to get the shown `ax` object as a numpy array for furhter processing without rewriting the code?

Comment: The numpy array that is shown is still `some_image.astype(np.uint8)`, so why not simply use it?

Comment: More things as mentioned in the example code are done to ax, like adding text and rectangles, - which will miss in some_image

Comment: What is the problem with using the solution from the linked question?

Comment: Would [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096972/how-can-i-render-a-matplotlib-axes-object-to-an-image-as-a-numpy-array?rq=1) suit you more?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you I will take a look at it. The shown solution would lead me to rewrite the code (which is not from me), so I wanted to know if there was a more direct way. Thank you again

Comment: I don't see why you would rewrite any code. The solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355930/matplotlib-figure-to-image-as-a-numpy-array) you link to can be directly applied to your case, by just adding the lines `ax.figure.canvas.draw(); image = np.fromstring(ax.figure.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype='uint8')`. Also the solution in the question I link to can be appended after the code. The main difference is that the former would give you the complete canvas, while the latter would give you only the axes `ax`.

Comment: I actually added this to my code, however it is serialized in a 1dim array - is it possible to know the original dimensions to which it could be reshaped?

Comment: The size of "image" is (7680000,1) and I cannot figure out what the original size might be

Comment: Did you actually read [the comment below the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355930/matplotlib-figure-to-image-as-a-numpy-array#comment72722681_35362787)?

Comment: I guess I have to add more than the mentioned code in your previous comment when this occurs, like canvas, fig etc. ?

Comment: `ax`, `ax.figure`, `ax.figure.canvas`, what else do you need?